# Swift 3 results with compile errors after Pod install error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, watchkit, swift3

After migrating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3, I have these complie errors:

First:

> error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/Alamofire-watchOS/Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Alamofire-watchOS.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Second:

> error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/SwiftyJSON-watchOS/SwiftyJSON-watchOS.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “SwiftyJSON-watchOS.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyApp Watch app Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

end
```

pod install error:

```
TEMPLATE END

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

```
Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
```

Comment: Do you use Cocoapods ?

Comment: @bogdanf Yes I do.

Comment: Did you update the cocoapods? What is in your Podfile?

Comment: Put it in the question. Don't put code into a comment.

Comment: Can you try a clean `pod install` ?

Answer (score -4):

```
    i)Clean(cmd+shift+k )
```

[image]

```
    ii)Pod Update 
    iii)Run (cmd+r)
```

[image]